# How to do wall post in WAP based facebook mobile app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall, wap

I'm doing a facebook application for (WAP based)mobile browser. I need to show the post dialog. When i use the following code for wall post it show error.

```
http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id='.$app_id.'&redirect_uri=$redirect_url&display=wap
```

**The error is:**

```
API ERROR CODE:3
API Error Description: Unknown Method
Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type
```

While I give display type as 'touch' in the above mentioned URL it works fine in the touch devices. But no form displayed in the wap browser.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, because their documentation does mention that is the method to do it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

I notice an error in your PHP though (unclosed apostrophe):

It should be:

```
'http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id='.$app_id.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_url.'&display=wap'
```

Here is a similar issue on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/177

Also, check out facebook's bug tracker: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net and perhaps file your bug there and then link to it from here.